# Separating Customize settings from other Init-file settings

Tags: init-file, customize

Currently all my settings that come from the customize interface are placed in:

```
(custom-set-variables

  '(menu-bar-mode nil)
  '(ivy-mode t)
  '(blink-cursor-mode nil)
  '(hl-line-mode nil)
  '(inhibit-startup-buffer-menu t)
  '(inhibit-startup-screen t)
  '(initial-scratch-message nil)
  '(scroll-bar-mode nil)
  '(show-paren-mode t)
  '(tool-bar-mode nil)
)
```

However, these settings eventually get buried inside the auto generated code that accumulates over time.

I would like to move some of these settings outside of the customize-interface into their own dedicated section so that I can keep track of them easily.

From what I understand I can't create a second custom-set-variables section because that's reserved for the auto generated code.

I don't know elisp well enough to know how to do this effectively.

Some guides suggest placing this anywhere in the init file:

```
(menu-bar-mode -1)
```

I've also seen this version:

```
(menu-bar-mode 0)
```

But this doesn't seem to work for all settings and some of them just give errors at startup. like this one for example:

```
(ivy-mode 1)
```

Results in:

```
Symbol's function definition is void: ivy-mode
```

So what is the right way to organize settings outside of the customize-interface?

And how do these formats differ? `-1` `0` `1` `t` `nil` etc.

** Answer in comments.

Comment: You'd need to `require` the correct package before activating the mode.  Additionally, if you want to learn more about the arguments that the function can take, you can hit M-x describe-function RET RET while on the function's name.

Comment: This helped a little. It says that positive arguments enable the mode and anything else disables it. So I'm guessing -1 and 0 are the same thing. It says if called from lisp, the mode is disabled if the argument is nil or omitted which explains the `nil` and `t` from the customize section. I'm still a little unsure as to what's the difference between `'(function t)` and `(function 1)` isn't everything in the init file just Lisp?

Comment: In a way, you are confusing variables and functions; the custom-set-variable function sets… variables! But really, this is slightly more complicated, since setting, say, `menu-bar-mode` to 1 wouldn't have any effect but *customizing it* would.  And yes, everything is just Lisp.

Comment: @Michaël Thanks, I was indeed confusing variables an functions. I had to use `(menu-bar-mode 0)` for functions and `(setq-default initial-scratch-message nil)` for variables. Thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

Set variable `custom-file`.  If defined, that is the file the Customize uses, to save and update your custom settings, instead of using your init file (e.g. `~/.emacs`).  Just add this to your init file:

```
(setq custom-file "/LOCATION/OF/YOUR/INIT/FILE/FILENAME")
```

And load that file at an appropriate place in your init file:

```
(load-file custom-file)
```

This lets you reserve your init file for Lisp customizations/settings that you make.  It keeps Customize out of your init file, so the two of you don't step on each other.  (Everyone should use `custom-file` (or some similar mechanism), IMHO.)